# Нахождение всех возможных путей из одной точки в другую в дереве - Python

Tags: python, графы, дерево

У меня есть код для нахождения первого попавшегося пути между заданными точками

```
'''
функция обхода дерева - поиск первого попавшегося пути между двумя узлами

graph = {'A': ['B', 'C'],
         'B': ['C', 'D'],
         'C': ['D'],
         'D': ['C'],
         'E': ['F'],
         'F': ['C']}
'''


def search_path(graph, start, end, path=[]):
    path += start
    if start == end: return path
    if start not in graph: return None
    for node in graph[start]:
        if node not in path:
            newpath = search_path(graph, node, end, path)
            if newpath: return newpath
    return None
```

Я пытаюсь изменить его, чтобы найти все возможные пути. Застрял на следующем моменте: как вернуть строку с уже найденным путем для следующей итерации цикла поиска из уже пройденной вершины - подставив в эту строку путь только до текущей вершины. Так же вопрос: как положить объявление списка всех путей внутрь функции, чтобы он потом не обнулялся при итерировании.

```
newpaths = []     # !ОБЪЯВЛЕНИЕ СПИСКА
def search_all_paths(graph, start, end, path=[]):
    path += start
    if start == end: return path
    if start not in graph: return None
    for node in graph[start]:
        if node not in path:
            newpath = search_all_paths(graph, node, end, path)
            if newpath:
                print(newpath, newpaths, path)
                if newpath != newpaths:
                    newpaths.append(newpath)
                newpath = []
                path = []              # **!ВОТ ЭТОТ ПУТЬ!!!**
                print('!!!', newpath, newpaths, path)
    return newpaths
```

Всем спасибо за внимание!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# Вывод всех путей из источника в пункт назначения.
# Этот код предоставлен Neelam Yadav
# Адаптирован Александром Драгункиным

from collections import defaultdict

# Класс направленного графа, использует представление списка смежности   
class Graph:

    def __init__(self, vertices):
        # Нет. вершин
        self.V = vertices

        # словарь по умолчанию для хранения графа
        self.graph = defaultdict(list)

    # функция добавления ребра в граф
    def addEdge(self, u, v):
        self.graph[u].append(v)

    '''Рекурсивная функция для печати всех путей от 'u' до 'd'.
    visit [] отслеживает вершины в текущем пути.
    path [] хранит актуальные вершины, а path_index является текущим
    индексом в path[]'''

    def printAllPathsUtil(self, u, d, visited, path):

        # Пометить текущий узел как посещенный и сохранить в path
        visited[list(self.graph.keys()).index(u)] = True
        path.append(u)

        # Если текущая вершина совпадает с точкой назначения, то
        # print(current path[])
        if u == d:
            print(path)
        else:
            # Если текущая вершина не является пунктом назначения
            # Повторить для всех вершин, смежных с этой вершиной
            for i in self.graph[u]:
                if visited[list(self.graph.keys()).index(i)] == False:
                    self.printAllPathsUtil(i, d, visited, path)

        # Удалить текущую вершину из path[] и пометить ее как непосещенную
        path.pop()
        visited[list(self.graph.keys()).index(u)] = False

    # Печатает все пути от 's' до 'd'
    def printAllPaths(self, s, d):

        # Отметить все вершины как не посещенные
        visited = [False] * (self.V)

        # Создать массив для хранения путей
        path = []

        # Рекурсивный вызов вспомогательной функции печати всех путей
        self.printAllPathsUtil(s, d, visited, path)



# Создаём граф
graph = {'A': ['B', 'C'],
         'B': ['C', 'D'],
         'C': ['D'],
         'D': ['C'],
         'E': ['F'],
         'F': ['C']}

g = Graph(len(graph.keys()))
for i, v in graph.items():
    for e in v:
        g.addEdge(i, e)

s = 'A'
d = 'C'
print ("Ниже приведены все различные пути от {} до {} :".format(s, d))
g.printAllPaths(s, d)
```

В результате:

```
Ниже приведены все различные пути от A до C :
['A', 'B', 'C']
['A', 'B', 'D', 'C']
['A', 'C']
```

Answer (score 1):

В **дереве** путь между вершинами всегда **единственный**

Если задача всё-таки стоит для графа общего вида (судя по тому, что в C входят две дуги):

Для нахождения всех простых путей в заданную вершину нужно помечать пройденные вершины, чтобы не использовать их на дальнейших уровнях рекурсии, но эти пометки не должны быть глобальными.

Пример рекурсивной реализации на Delphi [отсюда](http://www.delphikingdom.ru/asp/answer.asp?IDAnswer=56734) для небольшого числа вершин (до 32), для хранения текущих пометок используются биты целого числа.

Двумерный массив `Adj` работает как словарь со списками, `shl` - битовый сдвиг влево `<<`

Забит граф в виде шестиугольника с большим циклом 013652, и вершина 4 соединена с 0,3,5

```
var
  Adj: array of array of Byte;
  Src, Dest: Integer;

  procedure FindRoute(V: Integer; Used: Integer; Route: string);
  var
    i, W: Integer;
  begin
    if V = Dest then
      Memo1.Lines.Add(Route)
    else
      for i := 0 to High(Adj[V]) do begin
        W := Adj[V, i];
        if (Used and (1 shl W)) = 0 then
          FindRoute(W, Used or (1 shl W), Route + IntToStr(W) + ' ');
      end;
  end;

begin
  SetLength(Adj, 7);
  SetLength(Adj[0], 3);
  SetLength(Adj[1], 2);
  SetLength(Adj[2], 2);
  SetLength(Adj[3], 3);
  SetLength(Adj[4], 3);
  SetLength(Adj[5], 3);
  SetLength(Adj[6], 2);
  Adj[0, 0] := 1;
  Adj[1, 0] := 0;
  Adj[0, 1] := 2;
  Adj[2, 0] := 0;
  Adj[0, 2] := 4;
  Adj[4, 0] := 0;
  Adj[1, 1] := 3;
  Adj[3, 0] := 1;
  Adj[2, 1] := 5;
  Adj[5, 0] := 2;
  Adj[3, 1] := 4;
  Adj[4, 1] := 3;
  Adj[3, 2] := 6;
  Adj[6, 0] := 3;
  Adj[4, 2] := 5;
  Adj[5, 1] := 4;
  Adj[5, 2] := 6;
  Adj[6, 1] := 5;
  Src := 0;
  Dest := 3;
  FindRoute(Src, 1 shl Src, IntToStr(Src) + ' ');
end;

выдача
0 1 3 
0 2 5 4 3 
0 2 5 6 3 
0 4 3 
0 4 5 6 3
```