# Как получить все возможные пути?

Tags: python, алгоритм, поиск-пути

Я использую алгоритм Ли. У меня есть вот такая карта :

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но как получить все пути от e до 0 по цифрам ?

Тоесть (x,y) path1 = [(3,3),(4,3),(4,2),(4,1) ...], path2 = [(3,3),(3,2),(3,1),(3,0),(2,0)...] ... pathN где все пути должны быть в списке paths

Карта эта двухмерный список maps[y][x]. Как это реализовать на python ?

Answer (score 1):

Выполнить поиск в ширину (алгоритм Ли - это его разновидность) или в глубину. В отличие от обычной реализации пометки о прохождении вершин при рекурсивной реализации должны быть не глобальными, а локальными, и передаваться на следующий уровень рекурсии

[Пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/925076/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%85-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D1%83%D1%8E-%D0%B2-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B5-python/925142#925142)